# Values of ket vectors in Julia

Tags: julia

I can't figure out how to get specific elements/ values of a ket vector in Julia language. I tried to call a specific index of the ket vector using [index], like one does with a regular vector, but that does not seem to work with kets.

Kets are available in the QuantumOptics.jl package. So for a simple example, if I would define a ket myself:

```
basis = FockBasis(2)
x = Ket(basis, [1,3,2])
```

which gives output:

```
Ket(dim=3)
 basis: Fock(cutoff=2)
 1.0
 3.0
 2.0
```

If I then try to get an element of the ket, I would try it like this:

```
x[1]
```

which gives an error:

```
MethodError: no method matching getindex(::Ket{FockBasis{Int64},Array{Int64,1}}, ::Int64)
```

and I can't access the seperate elements of the ket.

Comment: https://github.com/qojulia/QuantumOptics.jl/issues/299  it simply doesn't have `getindex` implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the easiest way to get the `j` coefficient for a `ket` is just to access the j value for the `data` property of the `ket`. For your example you can just do

```
j = 1
j_coeff = x.data[j]
```